# Oracle correlated subquery issue

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have the following schema

```
Invoices
=================
invoice_number
account_id
invoice_amount
invoice_date
status ("Paid","Not Paid")
```

I'm trying to write a query to get all invoices with the following information ...

- invoice number
- invoice date
- account id
- invoice amount
- amount of last paid invoice for this account id (prior to the invoice date on this line)

I'm having an issue with the last item (amount of last paid invoice). So far I have ...

```
select 
inv2.invoice_number,
inv2.invoice_date,
inv2.account_id,
inv2.invoice_amount,
(
select * from (
    select inv.invoice_amount
      from invoices inv
      where inv.account_id = inv2.account_id
      and inv.status = 'PAID'
      and inv.invoice_date < inv2.invoice_date
      order by inv.invoice_date desc
    )
where rownum <=1
) as last_paid_amount
from
invoices inv2
```

I'm trying to refactor this to not use a correlated subquery, as the size of my dataset makes this very costly. How can I refactor to use a non-correlated subquery. Is this even possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I probably messed up `order by` clause here, as I have no opportunity to test it right now, but the idea is in using LAG function:

```
select 
  inv2.invoice_number,
  inv2.invoice_date,
  inv2.account_id,
  inv2.invoice_amount,
  lag(invoice_amount) over(
    partiton by account_id 
    order by invoice_date, decode(status, 'PAID', 1, 0)  
  ) last_paid_amount
from
invoices inv2
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, in order for LAG to work, there must be no more than 1 paid invoice.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, case when rnk = 1 then invoice_amount end as last_paid_amount
from(select 
inv2.invoice_number,
inv2.invoice_date,
inv2.account_id,
inv2.invoice_amount,
row_number() over(partition by invoice_number, account_id, (case when status = 'PAID' then 0 else 1 end), invoice_date desc) as rnk
from
invoices inv2) a
```

BTW, I am not sure LAG will work here.